# Is it possible to instantiate 2 Thread inside an Asynctask class doInBackground() in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, background-process

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Thread a = new Thread(new Tread1()).start();
        Thread b = new Thread(new Tread2()).start();
    }
}

class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    }
}

class Thread2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Is this possible instantiate 2 tread inside an asynctask in android?
What are the pros and cons of this style?

Comment: `doInBackground` is already running as a background thread, so why start another two threads from a background thread? A better approach would be to starts two AsyncTasks.

Comment: but is it posible to create Threads inside an Asynctask?

Comment: I've never tried it, since it doesn't seem like a good idea. But why don't you try it?

Comment: i want to create something like syncronized method that tread1 and tread2 will not run until there a value of the String s = "name"; somthing like that, how to create somthing like that using syncronized method? using Thread only

Comment: You can do that. You can start n no of Threads through async task, but that threads should be created in Main. I never tried with creating thread in AsyncTask.